# Switching back and forth between mobile and standard views with css / php styleswitcher

Tags: php, css, mobile

Site in question is here:

http://autisticadovcacy.uniongraphics.org

I originally designed this using one css file for default, print, and mobile styles, using
`@media print` and `@media only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)` to separate those styles.

I also have separate stylesheets for a couple of accessibility-related modifications (type size increases, contrast changes). I'm using a PHP styleswitcher script to allow the user to switch these styles manually. I link to the styleswitcher in the header like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/asan/css/switcher.php?default=style.css" type="text/css" />
```

and define the default style as `style.css`.

This was all working fine until the client said they wanted to provide a way for users to switch back to the default layout from a mobile device. I figured I'd pull out all my mobile styles into a separate stylesheet, add an extra link in the header file to load that stylesheet using the same media query as before, and then add a style-switching link in the footer to allow users to switch back to the main stylesheet if the prefer.

But when I removed my mobile styles from the main stylesheet and added this line in the header after loading the main stylesheet:

```
<link media="handheld, only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wp-content/themes/asan/css/mobile.css" />
```

…the mobile styles are no longer coming last in the cascade somehow. The mobile.css file is loading, but only styles marked !important are being displayed; everything else is defaulting to the main stylesheet.

I thought maybe this was because the mobile stylesheet was being loaded outside of the styleswitcher script, so I tried

```
<link media="handheld, only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wp-content/themes/asan/css/switcher.php?default=mobile.css" />
```

but that doesn't work either.

Can anybody find my error in how I set this up, and/or recommend a better way to allow users to switch between standard and mobile views (short of creating a completely separate mobile site and using a redirect, which I'm hoping to avoid)?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else dealing with this problem -- I used the Device Theme Switcher WP plugin: https://github.com/jamesmehorter/device-theme-switcher/. The plugin allows you to define separate themes for handhelds and tablets and uses User Agent detection to send visitors to the appropriate theme, but also lets you include a "View Full Site" link in your mobile layouts so users can return to the standard view if they want.