# How to allow user to switch back to standard view from a mobile device (CSS)

Tags: css, mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Switching back and forth between mobile and standard views with css / php styleswitcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458435/switching-back-and-forth-between-mobile-and-standard-views-with-css-php-styles)

If I have all my styles in a single stylesheet, using `@media only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)` to define mobile styles, is there a way to allow users to switch back to standard view even if they view the site from a mobile device?

I tried putting my mobile styles in a separate sheet and using a styleswitcher script, but I can't get that to work. Is there a way to do it with a single stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody else dealing with this problem -- I used the Device Theme Switcher WP plugin: https://github.com/jamesmehorter/device-theme-switcher/. The plugin allows you to define separate themes for handhelds and tablets and uses User Agent detection to send visitors to the appropriate theme, but also lets you include a "View Full Site" link in your mobile layouts so users can return to the standard view if they want.

Answer (score 0):

"Workaround" using multiple stylesheets:

You could create a button with a JavaScript Function that edits the header using [innerHTML](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php).

Therefore you use onclick on a button to execute a JavaScript function that contains innerHTML to cut out the device specific loading of a stylesheet and replace it by the stylesheet for computers only.

This means of course you need three stylesheets again. One for mobile styles only, one for desktop styles only and one with the common ones.

```
<link href="stylesMobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)">
<link href="stylesDesktop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 480px)">
<link href="stylesCommon.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

Cut out the 1st and the 2nd line and replace them with a simple loading of "stylesDesktop.css" with media="screen"

I hope this helps.

PS: I can't think of user friendly way to "override" the @media property. For testing purposes I assume faking the user agent should work.